# Says "Cannot Find Symbol - variable V"

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Color {
    public void main() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter your choice");
        System.out.println("Enter V for Violet");
        System.out.println("Enter I for Indigo");
        System.out.println("Enter B for Blue");
        System.out.println("Enter G for Green");
        System.out.println("Enter Y for Yellow");
        System.out.println("Enter O for Orange");
        System.out.println("Enter R for Red");
        char choice;
        choice = (char) br.read();
        switch (choice) {
        case V:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Violet");
            break;
        case I:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Indigo");
            break;
        case B:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Blue");
            break;
        case G:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Green");
            break;
        case Y:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Yellow");
            break;
        case O:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Orange");
            break;
        case R:
            System.out.println("The spectrum color is Red");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
        }
    }
}
```

it says that ----> `cannot find symbol - variable v`... when i'm trying to code it in bluej. I'm currently learning to do java programming and this is my first basic java program.

Comment: your all choices are char so you need write it as `case 'V':` and so on

Comment: Class names should begin with a capital letter according to the naming convention (`color` should be `Color`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try making your letters actual chars:

```
case 'V':

        System.out.println("The spectrum color is Violet");

        break;
```

What you're doing now is checking whether choice is the variable `V`, which, of course, does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To have character literals in Java, you need to use single quotes. Additionally, you probably want to accept both upper and lower case *v*. So you can do it like this:

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(choice))
{
   case 'V':
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You should compare chars. Try `case 'V'`.

Answer (score -2):

Check case sensitive. 'V' 'v'...